# are there any mirrors for boot-repair-disk-64bit.iso?

Tags: boot, grub2

Trying to recover from a grub error so I'm downloading http://sourceforge.net/projects/boot-repair-cd/. Sourceforge is absurdly slow, it's going to take an hour at least to download 500MB. Are there any better places to get this file? How about torrents (can't find it there, but maybe someone else knows a trick)?

Comment: Sourceforge links usually download fast, at least for me.

Comment: @karel I picked a mirror about 20 mins ago, still have 21 mins left on a 500MB file

Comment: FYI, if you have any Ubuntu live bootable ISO & an internet connection (or the downloaded .deb) you can just add a PPA & install boot-repair in 3 terminal  lines https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair#A2nd_option_:_install_Boot-Repair_in_Ubuntu

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are 12 available mirrors in different locations worldwide for downloading boot-repair-disk-64bit.iso. The mirrors for boot-repair-disk-64bit.iso are listed at [this link](https://sourceforge.net/settings/mirror_choices?projectname=boot-repair-cd&filename=boot-repair-disk-64bit.iso).

Comment: Ahh, that "Mirrors" link is really tiny, I missed it.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a link I googled, [burnbit.com torrent](http://burnbit.com/torrent/261130/boot_repair_disk_64bit_iso), but I can't vouch for except I used it without noticing any problem